# Apache htaccess rewrite ignoring Url Encoding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have just updated and I am currently setting all of the 301 Redirects in Apache's htaccess file. All redirects are working with the current format.

```
Redirect 301 /old+url+4343/ http://www.newsite.com/new-url-here/
```

But I've noticed a lot of old urls have some encoding - mainly ones with questions for titles. Apaches htaccess seems to ignore the encoding or just flop and not do anything. This, for example does not work;

```
Redirect 301 /old+question+title%3F/ http://www.newsite.com/new-question-title%3F/
```

In this case the %3F should be a question mark (?). I can visit the site normally if I copy and paste the url - that works just fine.

I have also tried setting the Charset in htaccess to see if that work but unfortunately it didnt, this was the code;

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Any ideas on why Apache would ignore url encoding and how I could overwrite that?

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` directive is very limited, better to use `RewriteRule` for regex capabilities and flags like `NE`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old\+question\+title\x3F/ /new-question-title\%3F/ [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: btw this is properly tested rule so I would appreciate a reason of downvote here

Comment: Hi @anubhava , thank you for the answer - unfortunately it doesn't seem to work (I have not downvoted by the way). The htaccess file seems to be ignoring the rule like before. Do I need to escape any slashes in the url for directories?

Comment: Can you tell me full URL you used to great and location of this htaccess?